# How to use regex to find a keyword in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

```kotlin
fun main () {

    val keyWords = listOf<String>("plus", "minus",
        "divided by", "multiplied by", "what is")

    val userInput : String? = readLine()
    val rx = Regex( "\\W${keyWords.joinToString(separator = "|")}")
    val result = keyWords

    if (rx.matches(userInput)){
        print("True")
    }
}
```

I keep on getting the error of type mismatch and that it requires a Char sequence. I've tried different methods but I still haven't been able to find a solution.

> Help me obi wan Kenobi you're my only hope

Comment: The problem is immediately visible through syntax highlighting, you're using `"` inside a string literal, how is the programming language supposed to know where the string literal ends? You need to escape them or use raw strings

Comment: There is no problem with using `"` within `${}` expression.

Comment: @Chase the code inside the `${}` is raw code, doesn't interfere with strings whatsoever.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue is that userInput is nullable.

```
10:20: error: type mismatch: inferred type is String? but CharSequence was expected
    if (rx.matches(userInput)){
```

`String` implements `CharSequence`.

One way to solve that would be to check for `null`:

```kotlin
val userInput : String? = readLine()
if (userInput != null) {
    val rx = Regex( "\\W${keyWords.joinToString(separator = "|")}")
    val result = keyWords
    if (rx.matches(userInput)){
        print("True")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding back the solution gets rid of the error but now it doesn't print true. Is there a reason why this is happening and how could I prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues that needs to be addressed:

- Since `userInput` is nullable, you should make sure you do not pass a `null` value to regex engine that only expects `CharSequence`
- The `.matches()` method requires a *full string match*, your regex only matches a part of a string, so you need to use `Regex#containsMatchIn`
- The `\W` at the start of your pattern only requires a non-word char before the first alternative. It won't allow a match at the start of the string either. You need to use to wrap your alternatives with `\b(?:...)\b`.

Fixed Kotlin snippet:

```
if (userInput != null) {
  val rx = Regex( "\\b(?:${keyWords.joinToString(separator = "|")})\\b")
  print (rx.containsMatchIn(userInput))
}
```

If your `keyWords` can contain special characters you will need to [escape special characters](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/escape.html) and then use either **unambiguous word boundaries**

```
val rx = Regex( "(?<!\\w)(?:${keyWords.map{Regex.escape(it)}.joinToString("|")})(?!\\w)")
```

or **whitespace boundaries**:

```
val rx = Regex( "(?<!\\S)(?:${keyWords.map{Regex.escape(it)}.joinToString("|")})(?!\\S)")
```

Comment: wiktor you are a life saver that really helped me a lot thank you <3<3